# How to convert string date to big int in hive with milliseconds

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have a string `2013-01-01 12:00:01.546` which represents a `timestamp` with milliseconds that I need to convert to a `bigint` without losing the milliseconds.

I tried unix_timestamp but I lose the milliseconds:

```
unix_timestamp(2013-01-01 12:00:01.546,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') ==> 1357059601
unix_timestamp(2013-01-01 12:00:01.786,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') ==> 1357059601
```

I tried with milliseconds format as well but no difference

```
unix_timestamp(2013-01-01 12:00:01.786,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS') ==> 1357059601
```

Is there any way to get milliseconds difference in hive?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came with so far.
If all your timestamps have a fraction of 3 digits it can be simplified.

```
with t as (select timestamp '2013-01-01 12:00:01.546' as ts)
select  cast ((to_unix_timestamp(ts) + coalesce(cast(regexp_extract(ts,'\\.\\d*',0) as decimal(3,3)),0)) * 1000 as bigint)
from    t
```

> 1357070401546

Verification of the result:

```
select from_utc_timestamp (1357070401546,'UTC')
```

> 2013-01-01 12:00:01.546000

Answer (score 1):

So apparently `unix_timestamp` doesn't convert milliseconds. You can use the following approach.

```
hive> select unix_timestamp(cast(regexp_replace('2013-01-01 12:00:01.546', '(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}).(\\d{3})', '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6.$7' ) as timestamp));
OK
1357063201
```

Comment: If you'll take another look on your test results you'll see that the result is in **seconds**. The milliseconds were truncated.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Thanks. I've edited. This looks alright, right?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz But I see a difference in the `bigint` value. Earlier `1357020001` now `1357063201`

Comment: The regex creates the exact same literal. Please check again

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Got it sir. So why is this the desired behavior? Is there a workaround to take milliseconds into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

Hive function `unix_timestamp()` doesn't convert the milli second part, so you may want to use the below:

```
unix_timestamp('2013-01-01 12:00:01.546') + cast(split('2013-01-01 12:00:01.546','\\\.')[1] as int) => 1357067347
unix_timestamp('2013-01-01 12:00:01.786') + cast(split('2013-01-01 12:00:01.786','\\\.')[1] as int) => 1357067587
```